# How do I find the sum of all numbers in STDIN even if there are non-digit characters?

Tags: perl

I have an assignment asking me to enter a sequence of numbers and characters each separated by a space and the sequence in ended by entering in "q" or "Q" followed by a space. Everything except the numbers should be discarded and we are to find the sum. So for example if the input is "1 12 a 2 5 P Q" then we should expect to get "20" as the output.

So far I'm using

```
$input = <>;
$input =~ tr/0-9//cd;
```

to get only the numbers but what I want is to split them up and get the sum. Right now the output would be 11225 and I want "1+12+2+5" and get the sum.

Comment: Perhaps [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)?

Comment: Is the input on a single line, or can it be spread over multiple lines?  Is the Q or q always present?  Is it always the last thing on the line? What if the input contains "`12A Z99`"; is the answer 111?  What about "`A9B8C D7E6F`"; is the answer 30?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '$s=0;($line)=/(.*?)[Qq]/;while($line=~/(\d+)/g) {$s+=$1} print "$s\n"'
```

**Explanation:**

Strips the trailing part of each line starting with a Q or a q,  then scan the remaining part for isolated positive integers and adds these together.

Answer (score 0):

First, strip out all characters that aren't numbers or spaces:

```
$input =~ s/[^0-9\s]//g;
```

Then, split on whitespace:

```
@digits = split(/\s/, $input);
```

Then you have a list of digits that you can add up.

Comment: How do you spot the Q or q that stops the parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Preserve spaces in your first step:

```
$input =~ tr/0-9 //cd;
```

Then split on spaces:

```
my @numbers = split ' ', $input;
```

(this is a special form of split that works like `split /\s+/` but also discards empty leading fields).

You probably want to start by getting rid of everything after a Q though:

```
$input =~ s/Q .*//i;
```

For what it's worth, I wouldn't have jumped to using tr here; I'd have started by spliting on spaces, then processed fields that were only digits until a Q was reached.